# What turned the colors psychedelic?

Tags: image-quality

Took this photo through the window of a Boeing 737 with a Fuji X-S1. This is an out-of-camera JPEG with no digital filters added. The water below the cloud was almost uniformly navy blue yet it came out with weird colors. Photos not taken through the airplane window look completely normal.

What would have caused these colors to appear? The colors were visible in the EVF but not to the naked eye.

[image: Sample]

Comment: Nice picture!  Not the common "out the airplane window" shot.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

What you're seeing is colors produced by the multiple layers of plastic you're looking through along with polarized light from either the plastic itself, the sky, or both. According to [this page](http://www.atoptics.co.uk/fz240.htm), the colors arise from constructive and destructive interference between the polarized sunlight passed through bifringent (double refracting) plastic windows.